# Linq-To-SQL .ToList() operator

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there a better way of doing this?

I have a Linq-To-SQL query that I need to return objects defined by abstract interfaces (e.g. IList<IUser>) rather than concrete objects (e.g. List<User>).

// get users from data context

```
        List<User> users;

        using (AbleridgeDataContext context = new AbleridgeDataContext())
        {

            users = (from u in context.Users select u).ToList();
        }

        // reassign concrete users to abstract interfaces

        IList<IUser> genericUsers = new List<IUser>();

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            IUser genericUser = user;
            genericUsers.Add(genericUser);
        }

        return genericUsers;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return context.Users.Cast<IUser>().ToList();
```

Alternatively:

```
List<IUser> users = new List<IUser>(context.Users);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cast to IUser in the projection part of the query:

```
    List<User> users;
    using (AbleridgeDataContext context = new AbleridgeDataContext())
    {
        return from u in context.Users select (IUser)u;
    }
```

The one change this would require is to make your function return `IEnumerable<IUser>` which would be better anyway because the query won't be executed until the caller begins enumerating.

Though you could also just use `ToList` still if you're not interested in changing that.

**Update**
Actually you probably will want to use `ToList` here because the using statement is disposing of your data context as soon as the function returns so a lazy query would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.  It will return `IEnumerable<IUser>`

```
using (AbleridgeDataContext context = new AbleridgeDataContext())
{
    return context.Users.Select((IUser)u);
}
```

If you really want IList then set your function return type to `IList<IUser>` and add a `.ToList()` to the end of the return statement.

Or

```
return context.Users.OfType<IUser>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare users as IList and cast User to IUser with linq.

`ToList` returns an IEnumerable, which is implemented my `IList` and `List`, so it really doesn't matter which one you declare `users` as.

```
    IList<IUser> users;
    using (AbleridgeDataContext context = new AbleridgeDataContext())
    {
        users = (from u in context.Users select u).Cast<IUser>().ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

Have you tried `context.Users.ToList<IUser>()`?

Also regarding the context, the ToList method will force the query to be evaluated so the result will be available after the context is disposed.